# Meeting invite sent to users also getting sent to group user is in

Tags: email, active-directory, microsoft-outlook, exchange-2003

When someone sends a meeting invite addressed only to me it also gets sent to a group I am in and everyone in that group gets the meeting invite also.  How do I remove that group from getting invites addressed to me.

Server 2003, Exchange 2003, Outlook 2007

Comment: Possible that they are sending the request to an email address which is for a group?

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://serverfault.com/questions/224720/meeting-invite-sent-to-users-also-getting-sent-to-group-user-is-in).

Answer (score 1):

I found out what was causing it.  I had the group set up as a delegate in Outlook under Tools—Options—Delegates.  That caused it to send the meeting invite to the group.  After I removed it stopped sending the invite to the group.